# Long lines don't wrap when characters are input by number

Tags: xetex, line-breaking

Why doesn't the following long line wrap and how to force it to?

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage{english}
\setotherlanguage{arabic}

\newfontfamily\arabicfont[Script=Arabic, Scale=1]{Tahoma}

\begin{document}
This is a very long line that normally needs to be wrapped:
\\
\textarabic{\char64474\char64475\char64474\char64475\char64474\char64475\char64474\char64475\char64474\char64475\char64474\char64475\char64474\char64475\char64474\char64475\char64474\char64475\char64474\char64475\char64474\char64475\char64474\char64475\char64380\char64381\char64380\char64381\char64380\char64381\char64380\char64381\char64380\char64381\char64380\char64381\char64380\char64381\char64380\char64381\char64380\char64381\char64380\char64381\char64380\char64381\char64380\char64381\char64380\char64381\char64380\char64381\char64380\char64381\char64380\char64381\char64380\char64381\char64380\char64381\char64380\char64381\char64380\char64381\char64380\char64381\char64380\char64381\char64380\char64381\char64380\char64381\char64380\char64381\char64380\char64381\char64380\char64381\char64380\char64381\char64380\char64381}

Same thing with a space filled character line like this one:
\\
\textarabic{\char64474 \char64475 \char64474 \char64475 \char64474 \char64475 \char64474 \char64475 \char64474 \char64475 \char64474 \char64475 \char64474 \char64475 \char64474 \char64475 \char64474 \char64475 \char64474 \char64475 \char64474 \char64475 \char64474 \char64475 \char64380 \char64381 \char64380 \char64381 \char64380 \char64381 \char64380 \char64381 \char64380 \char64381 \char64380 \char64381 \char64380 \char64381 \char64380 \char64381 \char64380 \char64381 \char64380 \char64381 \char64380 \char64381 \char64380 \char64381 \char64380 \char64381 \char64380 \char64381 \char64380 \char64381 \char64380 \char64381 \char64380 \char64381 \char64380 \char64381 \char64380 \char64381 \char64380 \char64381 \char64380 \char64381 \char64380 \char64381 \char64380 \char64381 \char64380 \char64381 \char64380 \char64381 \char64380 \char64381 \char64380 \char64381 \char64380 \char64381 \char64380 \char64381}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I have edited my MWE accordingly. Please try it now. Same long line.

Comment: `\char` gobbles the space after it (like almost all TeX primitives), you need to either insert an explicite space `\charXXXX\ ` or end it with an empty group `\charXXXX{} ` (notice the trailing space in both cases). But anyway, why going through the pain of using `\char` and not inserting the text directly? A side note, don’t ever set Arabic in Tahoma, it is the most hideous popular Arabic typeface (it was designed for low res screens of the 90s).

Comment: Thank you so much. The space \ character did solve my issue. The reason I am using Tahoma is for inline Arabic text that doesn't defer the spacing between the lines. I know there are much more beautiful fonts such as "Arabic Typesetting" and "KFGQPC Uthman Taha Naskh", but they alter spacing, or otherwise have to be extremely small.

Comment: You may try Amiri font (included in latest TeX Live), or any other good font, after all the main utility of text is to be read comfortably.

Comment: @Nina: Since Khaled's answer seems to answer your question, please consider marking it as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below its vote count.

Answer (score 7):

`\char` gobbles the space after it (like almost all TeX primitives), you need to either insert an explicit space `\charXXXX\`   or end it with an empty group `\charXXXX{}`  (notice the trailing space in both cases).

Comment: Another way may be `\newcommand{\lit}[1]{\char#1 }` so that the input can be something like `\lit{64474}\lit{64475} \lit{64474}\lit{64475}` where spaces mark word breaks. The space after `#1` is important.